# Is it possible to send email using Adobe Acrobat XI using a different smtp settings other than for gmail, yahoo, or client?

Tags: javascript, adobe

I have a weird question.

I'm trying to email a pdf document as an attachment. There are a couple of ways to do this: using client, or webmail. We can set the settings for webmail for gmail and yahoo, or other, but "other" settings for my company doesn't work that is requested by adobe. Apparently, Adobe tries to create a message window which our company's policy for email doesn't allow.

Anyhow, is it possible to use javascript to add smtp settings and attach the pdf document? The only reason I'm trying to do this is because Outlook client is blocked for security outside the company network, and I usually have around 200 pdf documents that I have to send each day. If I'm in the network, then I can use the Outlook Client. But, if I'm out in the field or away from the network, I can only use web based office365. I want to be able to create a javascript for which I can add the smtp settings and send it. But I don't know how to do this. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use JavaScript to manipulate SMTP setting in any way. You'll be better of creating a back-end service on the server to send emails.

Comment: I figured it was not possible. But I put in the question just in case if somebody has any idea in making that possible in Adobe. Thanks for the response.